# Basis for the intersection of a family of topology

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $T_{\alpha}$ is a family of topologies on the same space $X$.

We already know that $\bigcap T_{\alpha}$ is also a topology on X.

Now, assume that $B_1$ is a basis of ${T_1}$, $B_2$ is a basis of $T_2$, etc.

What can we say about the basis of $T_{\alpha}$? Is there any relationship (representation) betwen bases of each topologis ${T_j}$ and their intersection $\bigcap T_{\alpha}$?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I do not see any obvious relationship though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried for their intersection and union, but it seems to be useless. So, I also wonder how can we express or represent the intersection space without basis?

Comment: The intersection topology definitely have a basis, but I do not see it could be obviously derived from B1, B2, ...

Comment: @TrầnLinh Note that if $B$ is a basis of $T$ then any subset $B'$ between $B\subseteq B'\subseteq T$ is a basis of $T$, including $T$ itself. In other words you can very easily extend any basis by adding open sets randomly. From that point of view I think that such relations would be extremely hard to formulate.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I agree with both of you ^^